# Confusion about Integrated Circuits analysis

Tags: rf

Since in integrated circuits on chips, the physical size of components including transmission lines is much smaller than the wavelength of frequencies around 1-3 GHz, why do we revert to microwave analysis: S parameters, reflection coefficients, the use of Smith chart, etc...? Why can't we just use analog circuit analysis exclusively? i.e. voltages and currents?

Answer (score 1):

> ... around 1-3 GHz, why do we revert to microwave analysis: S parameters, reflection coefficients, the use of Smith chart, etc...? Why can't we just use analog circuit analysis exclusively? i.e. voltages and currents?

Because to use voltages and currents, you have to **measure** voltages and currents, and that's very difficult at 3 GHz, at least to do it in a controlled and repeatable way. That's why we measure waves in a transmission line system, it's controlled and repeatable.

Once you're measuring waves, it's sensible to stick with parameters that work with those measurements, S parameters, reflection coefficients etc, rather than transforming them to voltages and currents, which would be possible, but would be a waste of effort.

Even if components are small, their electrical delay means that to cascade them, we still need to take account of their full set of S-parameters.